# How to style the inline label in Simple Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) checkbox which uses both a regular field label and an inline label:

```
<%= f.input :remove_default_template, 
  label: 'Advanced Option',
  inline_label: "Remove Header, Footer, and Department Name"
%>
```

And I need to add styling to the inline label.  How can I do this?  I would expect *something following this pattern* to work:

```
<%= f.input :remove_default_template, 
  label: 'Advanced Option',
  inline_label: "Remove Header, Footer, and Department Name",
  inline_label_html: 
  input_html: {class: "input_class"},               # THIS works
  wrapper_html: {class: "wrapper_class"},           # THIS works
  label_html: {class: "label_class"},               # THIS works  
  inline_label_html: {class: "inline_label_class"}  # THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!
%>
```

but the final line doesn't work:

```
inline_label_html: {class: "inline_label_class"}
```

Since Simple Form doesn't seem to support this option (at least under the name I expected, nor anything else that I could find), how can I accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a hint, not an inline label.

Then you can write a wrapper, which allows doing something like this

```
<%= f.input :subdomain, input_wrapper_html: { class: 'col-sm-4' } %>
```

And then your hints will be inline.

Please check here https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1035

Comment: interesting... does a hint for a checkbox *look* just like an inline label?  The example you linked to deals with a text field, not a checkbox, so I'm not sure how this will work